# To show Bijection from Quotient Vector Space to Range

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show the following and looking for hints how to start this problem better. 
Reading now Kreuzig's functional analysis -book.

> Let $[u] := u + Ker(A)$ for $u \in V$. Prove that $\tilde{A}[u] := Au$ gives a well-defined linear bijection $\tilde{A} : V / Ker(A) \to \text{Ran}(A).$

### My proposal

Direct proof. 
Let's show the basic two operations positive homogenity and absolute homogenity of the quotient vector space. 
Assume $\exists v \in V$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\left( ( u + \text{Ker}(A), [v] ) \right) 
\mapsto 
\left( [ u + \text{Ker}(A) + v ] \right)
\end{equation}
where $u \in V/Z$, $\text{Ker}(A) \in V/Z$ and $v \in V/Z$ so 
\begin{equation}
\left( [ u + \text{Ker}(A) + v ] \right) 
\in V/Z.
\end{equation}

Assume $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{K}$. 
Consider
\begin{equation}
\left( ( \lambda, u + \text{Ker}(A) \right) 
\mapsto [ \lambda + u + \text{Ker}(A) ]
\end{equation}
where $u + \text{Ker}(A) := \lambda v_{\vartheta}$ so 
\begin{equation}
[ \lambda + u + \text{Ker}(A) ] := [ \lambda (v) ] = [ \lambda v ]. 
\end{equation}

Trivially, $[0] \subset V / \text{Ker}(A)$. 
The vector space gives an equivalence relation on $V$, with equivalence classes 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
[u] &= { v \in V : u \sim v } \\
&= { u + z :  z \in \text{Ker}(A) }.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $u \in V / \text{Ker}(A)$.
Consequently, there is a well-defined linear bijection. $\square$

### Comments

However, I want to do this mathematically rigorously and I do not keep this sufficient. Probably, proof by contradiction or other view to the proof can be better.

How can you start the proof of the bijection from the Quotient vector space to Range better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I forgot while writing this up that this question was tagged "functional analysis", so I might be going into a bit too much detail for your tastes below. I've not read Kreyszig's book, and so I'm not 100% sure what the seemingly non-standard notation he's using is, but if this is about linear maps between vector spaces the discussion below applies.

---

Some of the steps you've made seem a bit ambiguous (e.g., what do you mean by $[u+\ker A + v]$? Is this the set of equivalence classes in $U/\ker A$ with representatives of the form $u+k+v$ for $k \in K$), but I think you're on the right track.

This is one instance of the First Isomorphism Theorem (for what I assume are vector spaces $U,V$ over a field $F$), and for fun I've provided a complete (and formal) proof in the sequel.

Assume $A: U \to V$ is a $F$-linear function, and define a map $\bar A: U/\ker A \to A(U)$ as follows: for each equivalence class $q \in U/\ker A$, fix $u \in q$ and define $\bar Aq = Au$.

**Claim:** $\bar A$ is well-defined, $F$-linear, and a bijection.

For simplicity in the proof, set $K = \ker A$.

**Proof of Well-Definedness:** We need to show that for any $q \in U/K$, if $u_1, u_2 \in q$ then $Au_1 = Au_2$. To do so, note that if $u_1,u_2 \in q$ then there exists $k \in K$ such that $u_2 = u_1 + k$, and consequently $Au_2 = Au_1 + Ak = Au_1$. Hence $\bar Aq$ is well-defined.

**Proof of $F$-Linearity:** If $\alpha_i \in F$ and $q_i = u_i + K \in U/K$ for $i = 1,2$, then $\alpha_1q_1+\alpha_2q_2 = (\alpha_1u_1+\alpha_2u_2)+K$ implies \begin{align*}
    \bar A(\alpha_1q_1 + \alpha_2q_2) = A(\alpha_1u_1 + \alpha_2u_2) = \alpha_1Au_1 + \alpha_2Au_2 = \alpha_1\bar Aq_1 + \alpha_2\bar Aq_2
\end{align*}
by the $F$-linearity of $A$, whence $\bar A$ is $F$-linear.

**Proof of Injectivity:** Note by $F$-linearity that $\bar A(u_1 + K) = \bar A(u_2 + K)$ if and only if $\bar A((u_1-u_2) + K) = 0$, and so it is enough to show that if $\bar Aq = 0$ then $q = 0 + K$. But this follows immediately, since if $q = u+K$ then $\bar Aq = Au = 0$ implies $u \in K$ and so $q = u+K = 0+K$.

**Proof of Sujectivity:** If $v \in A(U)$, then there exists $u \in U$ such that $Au = v$. Setting $q = u + K$, it follows that $\bar Aq = Au = v$, and so $\bar A$ is surjective.

Comment: Can this work also if the vector spaces $U, V$ are on $\mathbb{R}$? Instead of the field? In case of the field, I think it does not need to be ordered here, since no convexity is required here.

Comment: @Masi $F$ represents an arbitrary field in my proof, and so it could be $F = \mathbb{R}$ in particular. I haven't had time to look at the other question you've mentioned, but hourly someone else has provided a good answer. `:)`

Comment: I think it works also even on $\mathbb{C}$.